# JavaScript - .map()

Tags: javascript

Bom dia pessoal, eu tenho um array, entretanto eu desejo multiplicar apenas o índice 2 do array usando `.map()`. Abaixo estará um exemplo onde estou multiplicando todas as posições do array.

```
const nums = [1,2,3,4,5]

let result = nums.map(function(e, i, arr) {
    return e * 2 
})
console.log(result)
```

Como modificar somente a posição 2?

Comment: por favor verifique as resposta e assinale uma como resposta do seu post ...

Answer (score 2):

Se só queres modificar o indice 2 basta fazer assim:

```
nums[2] = nums * 2;
```

Assim mudas o valor interno da array sem precisar de reatribuir. Se quiseres usar o `.map()` que é a melhor solução muitas vezes podes fazer assim:

```
let result = nums.map(function(e, i, arr) {
    return i === 2 ? e * 2 : e; 
})
```

Comment: Boa!!! muito bom, isso mesmo que queria aprender! Muito obrigado!!